# visual studio 2013 c# developed app incompatible with windows 7, vista, windows 8, 8.1

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I have developed a 32 bit Visual C# application in Visual Studio 2013 (using Windows 7 64 bit) that targets the .Net 4 Framework so it runs on Windows XP, Vista, 7, 8, and 8.1. When I deploy the app to my Virtual machines to all those Windows versions, I have to set the compatibility for it to Windows XP Service Pack 2. Why is that? It uses a C++ dll in some of the options if that makes a difference (I compiled the dll with the /MD linking option since it is unmanaged code). Thanks in advance for any replies.

Answer (score -1):

I just found the settings in the app.manifest. It fixed it. You have to uncomment the lines for Windows Vista, 7, and 8 for the project to be supported on those operating systems.

Comment: If you intend to answer your own question to accept the answer then you should describe how to fix the problem and a little on what caused it.